# Can't change settings in Ubuntu 18.04 (Screen Lock)

Tags: 18.04, settings, privacy

I can't change any settings  inside `Screen Lock` portion as they are grayed out. Settings options for other categories seems okay.  
How can I fix this ?
[image]

Comment: couldnt figure it out. had to resort to `dconf reset -f /` (THIS RESETS ALL YOUR SETTINGS)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at [Ubuntu 18.10: Screen lock options grayed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090091/ubuntu-18-10-screen-lock-options-grayed-out/1114048)

In short, you can remove the "lockdown" of this setting by using the command

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false`