# Can not lock screen, screen lock never activates, and Super+L does nothing

Tags: 18.10, lock-screen

As stated in the title, when I open `Settings` and click on `Privacy` then `Screen Lock` all of the options are grayed out.

[image]

The `Blank Screen` setting in `Power` is set to 15 mins. Super+L is set in the `Keyboard` setting to lock screen, but never works. The only thing that seems to work is the `Switch User` in the upper right menu.

**GNOME shell extensions:**

- User Themes
- System-monitor

`$ xset q
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On`

Comment: This question is asked here also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090091/ubuntu-18-10-screen-lock-options-grayed-out. Maybe somewhat helpful.

Comment: Also you could just bring up the tty then login with user name and password then startx. Enable tty Ctrl alt f7 I believe